# AChart Engine Dail Chart Background Custamization

Tags: android, achartengine

I want to Know is it possible to customize dial chart's background  in  Achart Engine?
I want a background like speedometer such some indication colors have to be there like red,yellow and green, and its better if i can determine from which value to which each of these indications have to start and end.
Do we can get any sample codes from anywhere?
 Advanced thanks for all suggestions ,answers , sample codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with AChartEngine.
But you can checkout the code from SVN and customize it the way you need.

Comment: Thank you Dan, Yeah I have found it and customized already thanks for your reply...